# Close Animation will not run

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios4

In my iPhone app there is a window that appears over the main window.  Here is the code for my close button;

```
-(IBAction)cancel{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view removeFromSuperview]; 
//[_window addSubview:view2];
[UIView commitAnimations];}
```

The window closes correctly but the animation will not execute.  I do not understand why.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are removing the view from the superview *during* the animation. The animation does not occur because the view is gone. You should wait until after the animation finishes to remove to view, which you can do by setting a delegate and selector which is called when the animation is finished.

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

And then in

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: This kind of worked.  What happened is the Window animated but the window was still there.  Once the animation was done the window was removed.  So picture this; the window curls up, as it is the exact same window is "beneath" the curling window.  Then the window disappears.

Comment: I guess you will want to have to make sure whatever view you are transitioning to is behind the view you are removing.  I am pretty skeptical that "self.view" is the view you want to be removing.  I think you probably want to have two views, view1 and view2.  Put view1 in front of view2 (maybe add it as a subview after view2), then run this animation on it and remove it.